Wheels Not Moving in Open-Loop Configuration with ROS2 Control and Teleop
[1]I'm relatively new to ROS and have been working on a robot project. I am currently using ROS2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04. I've been following the tutorial series from Articulated Robotics, particularly the video titled "Using ros2_control to drive our robot". This tutorial employs a closed-loop setup for controlling a differential drive robot. However, my own setup is different as it operates under an open-loop configuration.
I've managed to adapt my my_controllers.yaml file for open-loop control, and my launch file executes without any errors, showing the diff_cont nodes as active. I'm attempting to control the robot using the teleop_twist_keyboard node, but the wheels are not responding to any keyboard inputs.
Here's what I've done so far:
Modified the controller configuration to suit an open-loop control.
Verified that the diff_cont and teleop_twist_keyboard nodes are active

Interestingly, when I test the setup with another package 'serial_motor_demo', it works fine. However, when I launch the file for the physical robot using my current configuration, the wheels do not move.
I suspect there might be some necessary adjustments I need to make either in the ROS2 control configuration or in the Arduino code (diffdrive_arduino) to fully adapt it to an open-loop system. Could anyone suggest what changes might be needed in the ros2 control setup or the Arduino firmware to handle open-loop control effectively?
Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
Here are my project files [1]: https://github.com/joeDonuts/firebot.git
